# Ошибка в запросе SQL #1064

Tags: sql, mariadb

При запросе

```
ALTER TABLE buyer_personals ADD inn MEDIUMTEXT NULL AFTER pinfl_hash ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

выдает ошибку

> #1064 - у вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC' на строке 1

Вопрос: как избавиться от ошибки?

Comment: Error code: 1118 Row size too large

Comment: `ROW_FORMAT` - атрибут таблицы, а не поля.

Comment: как правильно тогда?

Comment: Либо уберите вообще, либо выполните как отдельный action. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=48e471d4c3ee18746ce822156b02a196

Comment: да, но как после ошибки 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC' at line 1

Comment: у вас после повторного ввода без ошибок вышло

Comment: Вы слишком невнимательны для программиста.